# Element popup and disappears

Tags: jquery

I have used the jquery toggle function with an element. But every time I load the page the element pops up and disappears.

My code is here:--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#button").toggle(function(){
            jQuery("#feedback_form").animate({right:"0px"});

        },
        function(){
            jQuery("#feedback_form").animate({right:"-362px"});
            return false;
        }
    ); //toggle
});
```

The button element appears and disappears. I cant click it.

Comment: a fiddler or code sample will be helpful to understand issue better

Comment: Try to change its speed, make it slow

Comment: i have used jQuery('#button').show().toggle()............... but still not working

Comment: Are you trying to toggle that element on your button click.  From the code you have provided it looks like you are trying to toggle the amount of right on button click.  But what you have is invalid code as no argument for toggle takes 2 functions.  Try `jQuery("#button").click(function() { jQuery("#feedback_form").slideToggle({ direction:'right' }); })`

Comment: thanx but this is not working @Pete

Comment: Until you set up some sort of code snippet with an [MCVE], we can't really help you

Answer (score 0):

I've done it but a little bit different than original code:

JS:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  $('#feedback_form').toggleClass("move");
});
```

CSS:

```
.move{
  right:-362px !important;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/g2hncbdu/5/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you toggle your button element that's why your element gets hide while loading or ready:

Try like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    jQuery("#feedback_form").toggle(function(){
            jQuery("#feedback_form").animate({right:"0px"});

        },
        function(){
            jQuery("#feedback_form").animate({right:"-362px"});
            return false;
        }
    ); //toggle
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajesh26aug/g2hncbdu/7/)